# Begin/end a logical block?

Tags: tex-core

Can I create a logical block (like HTML div element), so I can apply features like `\centering` locally, but not affect the outside environment?

Comment: You can use them in a group `\bgroup.....\egroup`. Whatever is used is applied only within that group.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. The most basic of these blocks are braces `{` (for opening) and `}` (for closing). You can also use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` or `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.

When defining your own environment `<env>`, using `\begin{<env>}` ... `\end{<env>}` necessarily forms a group, localizing most modifications.